# Not able to install extensions in VS code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, babeljs, eslint

I am new to VS code trying to set it up for web development. I have downloaded two extensions babel Javascript and ES lint but when I am double-clicking on them, the following error comes. Can someone help me in solving this? Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cMhz.png

> Install Failed
>
> The Install of 'ESLint' was not successful for all the selected products. FOr more information, click on the install log link at the buttom of the dialog.
>
> ESTLint
>
> One of more extensiong are for Visual Studio Code. Try installing them in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Where did you download them from?  Did you try going to the extensions tab in VS Code and installing from there?

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I downloaded it from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint. And yes I tried to search both bable javascript and ESlint in extensions manager but no results found for both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you already have [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) installed?

you can either grab it from [the marketplace here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) and it'll request to open VS Code to install, or once you have VS Code:

- open VS Code
- Ctrl + Shift + X  this will open open the Extensions panel
- Type ESLint in the search bar.
- Find the ESLint extension in the search results
- click the green Install button next to it

Answer (score -2):

You could just download Visual Studio instead of Visual Studio Code. These are different products. (I just ran into the same problem)

Comment: Visual studio is paid while visual studio code is free. Hence, this solution won't work for everyone

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31749343)